# Maven for PHP won't find the right archetype

Tags: php, maven, maven-archetype

I try to create a new php project with maven by using this command mvn archetype:generate , but it won't find the mavenphp achetype, instead it gives me a list of a lot of archetypes. I configured my settings.xml with the info provided here http://www.php-maven.org/prepare.html but it still does not work. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post the actual error message. Also, if you run maven with the -X (debug mode), you'll get a lot more information about the problem.

Comment: Hi, this is the message it shows 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[INFO] No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart

Comment: mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=php5-zend-archetype -X

 It gives me the following error

 [DEBUG] Archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:php5-zend-archetype:1.0 doesn't exist
org.apache.maven.archetype.downloader.DownloadNotFoundException: Requested org.apache.maven.archetypes:php5-zend-archetype:jar:1.0 download does not exist.
 at org.apache.maven.archetype.downloader.DefaultDownloader.download(DefaultDownloader.java:78)

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm talking nonsense here, but is there something like Archetype Repositories that you could configure in your settings.xml? Or could you use a -DarchetypeRepository option?

Answer (score 0):

related to your previous comments:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=php5-zend-archetype
```

This assumes that the archetype version 1.0.0 is used. However this archetype version is not present. Use the following:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=php5-zend-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=2.0.0 -DarchetypeGroupId=org.phpmaven
```